# Limit of a series of a sequence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have troubles finding the limit of the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5+4n-1}{3^{2n+1}}$

So far I figured it'd easier to split the sum into:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5}{3^{2n+1}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n-1}{3^{2n+1}}$

= $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 5 \cdot\frac{1}{3^{2n+1}} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4n-1 \cdot \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}}$

And with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{w^n} = \frac{1}{w-1}$ you get the following terms:

$5\cdot \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}-1} + 4n-1\cdot \frac{1}{3^{2n+1}-1}$

which is bascially a sequence, but im stuck right here.. help is very appreciated!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) or [Statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) satisfies your needs better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be easily investigated with Mathematica.

Define the function

```
f[n_] := (4 + 4 n)/3^(2 n + 1)
```

To check if the sum is convergent:

```
Limit[f[n + 1]/f[n], n -> Infinity]
```

> 1/9

and also

```
Limit[f[n], n -> Infinity]
```

> 0

Or just simply

```
SumConvergence[f[n], n]
```

> True

```
ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, Range[10]}], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Black}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", Rotate["f(n)", 270 Degree]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Convergence plot"]
```

[image]

To plot the partial sums:

```
ListPlot[Accumulate@Table[f[n], {n, Range[10]}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Black}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", "Partial sums"}]
```

[image]

We see that the sum quickly plateaus. Let's finally find the value of the infinite sum:

```
sum = Sum[f[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> 17/48

```
N@sum
```

> 0.354167

One can do also

```
NSum[f[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> 0.354167