# Convergence and divergence of sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I find out if this sum converges or diverges?

I believe that is a question quite simple.

Until I looked in the documentation, but I think that I did not know how to do this.

```
Sum[(8 n + Sqrt[n])/(n^4 - n^2 + 5), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

[image]

I believe that is not only insert the sum. But i have to use another feature that i do not know what it was.

Comment: `NSum[(8 n + Sqrt[n])/(n^4 - n^2 + 5), {n, 1, Infinity}]` -> 3.50589

Comment: Related: [(126839)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126839/limit-of-a-series-of-a-sequence).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SumConvergence[(8 n + Sqrt[n])/(n^4 - n^2 + 5), n]
```

It returns True.

Answer (score 2):

When n is very large, it is like *1/n^3*, it is convergence.

```
Series[(8 n + Sqrt[n])/(n^4 - n^2 + 5), {n, \[Infinity], 2}]
```

with reutern $O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right)$, so it is convergence.

Comment: Your answer is not related to Mathematica.